.Password was unexpected at this time
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin [my-id].dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
.Password was unexpected at this time.
I want to push my local project to ECR Repo but I get stuck in my process. What can I do?
I expected the prompt to display "Login successful"

I have the same issue did you solve it?
